# Regex File Scraping

Tags: c, regex

I'm scrapping a email address in a file with regex.

Unfortunately my regex rule can not match with to this string :

`"         <font size=-1><a href=mailto:mrnours@citeweb.net>_ MR NOURS _</a></font>          "`;

I'm failling to find the reason why on stackoverflow, I hope someone could telle what is wrong on my rule.

This is my code to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void)
{
  int match;
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t pmatch[5];
  size_t nmatch = 5;
  const char *str_request = "         <font size=-1><a href=mailto:mrnours@citeweb.net>_ MR NOURS _</a></font>          ";

 const char *str_regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.(com|net|[a-zA-Z]{2})$";

  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
        {
          printf ("match\n");
          int start = pmatch[0].rm_so;
          int end  = pmatch[0].rm_eo;
          printf("%d - %d\n", start, end);
        }
      else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
        {
          printf("unmatch\n");
        }
    }
  puts ("\nPress any key\n");
  getchar ();
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Comment: Remove the `$` from the pattern.

Comment: @AeroX: this question has nothing to do with html

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini From the example string given being HTML tags, I suspect this could end up being an XY problem. The OP mentions scrapping & provides a HTML string, which likely means they will later want to scrape webpages.  Hence the Possible Duplicate pointing them in the direction of HTML Parsing instead of Regex.

Comment: It is not a duplicate of any kind as the issue is not the regex here, but how it is used in the C code.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are trying to match the substring as a whole word, thus, you used `$` (end-of-string) anchor at the end of the pattern. However, the substring you are looking for is not at the end of the input string.

Since `regex.h` does not support word boundaries, you can use a workaround:

```
const char *str_regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.(com|net|[a-zA-Z]{2}))([^a-zA-Z]|$)";
                                                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The value you need will reside in the capture group 1.

See this [C IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/Y3xwjo):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main (void)
{
  int match;
  int err;
  regex_t preg;
  regmatch_t pmatch[5];
  size_t nmatch = 4; // We have 4 groups as a result of matching: 0 - the whole match, and 3 capture groups
  const char *str_request = "         <font size=-1><a href=mailto:mrnours@citeweb.net>_ MR NOURS _</a></font>          ";

 const char *str_regex = "([a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\.(com|net|[a-zA-Z]{2}))([^a-zA-Z]|$)";

  err = regcomp(&preg, str_regex, REG_EXTENDED);
  if (err == 0)
    {
      match = regexec(&preg, str_request, nmatch, pmatch, 0);
      nmatch = preg.re_nsub;
      regfree(&preg);
      if (match == 0)
        {
          printf ("match\n");
          int start = pmatch[1].rm_so; // <- Changed from 0 to 1
          int end  = pmatch[1].rm_eo; // <- Changed from 0 to 1
          printf("%d - %d\n\"%.*s\"", start, end, pmatch[1].rm_eo - pmatch[1].rm_so, &str_request[pmatch[1].rm_so]);
        }  //                ^--^ Added a captured substring display
      else if (match == REG_NOMATCH)
        {
          printf("unmatch\n");
        }
    }
  puts ("\nPress any key\n");
  getchar ();
  return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
 }
```

Or just remove the `$` if you do not care about whole word matching.

Comment: Please check the answer, and if it worked for you please consider accepting.